# How to use filter operators with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy I can query filtering the result with `endswith` method:

```
session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid.endswith("z")).all()
```

Similar with `startswith`:

```
session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid.startswith("a")).all()
```

`contains` follows the same syntax:

```
session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid.contains('c')).all()
```

I wonder if `==` and `!=` operators could be replaced with the similar syntax.
So, instead of:

```
 session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid=='cfbb4cdb57').all()
```

it would be something like:

```
session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid.is('cfbb4cdb57')).all()
```

Comment: [`is_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.is_) maps to SQL `IS` and as such is not the same as equality. You could use the [dunder methods](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.__eq__), but that'd be an abomination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There is `.is_()` and `.isnot()` as well as calling `.__eq__()` explicitly.

However, note that `is` and `==` are [not the same in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python). From PEP8:

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not` , never the equality operators

So, I think you would want to use `==` (not `__eq__`) for non-singletons and `is_()` for comparing against `None`.

The full list of what are called queryable attributes is [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=startswith#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute).

Comment: This raises the error: `session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.uuid.is_('cfbb4cdb57')).all()`

Comment: It appears both `.is_(None)` and `.isnot(None)` expect `None` as their only argument. Supplying any other type (boolean, string, int) crashes the execution.

Comment: Right, I was trying to imply that in my answer. I'll update it to be more explicit.

Comment: How does that look?